# Adding a returned NULL into data frame as value

Tags: r, r-markdown, tidyverse

I have these vectors that I would like to make as a dataframe whilst having the 4th value also as a value instead of the 4th value being a "NULL" and stopping further processing

```
    a <- Dataset$price1
    b <- Dataset$price33
    c <- Dataset$price16
    d <- Dataset$price40

> a
[1] 0.76

> b
[1] 0.52

> c
[1] 0.93

> d
NULL
```

Consequently, this doesn't work

```
    test <- c(a,b,c,d)
```

**Desired outcome:**

```
> c(a,b,c,d)

[1] 0.76 0.52 0.93 0
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Do your vectors: ` a`, `b`, `c` and `d` comprise only one value each?

Comment: yes, you could also work with them directly, like
c(Dataset$price1, Dataset$price33, Dataset$price16,  Dataset$price40)
i changed it for clarity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach that relies on first creating a list, which can natively hold `NULL` values:

```
result <- sapply(list(a,b,c,d),function(x)ifelse(is.null(x),0,x))

result
#[1] 0.76 0.52 0.93 0.00

is.vector(result)
#[1] TRUE
```

As an aside, I would recommend against assigning variables to names shared by internal R functions, like `c`.

Data:

```
list2env(setNames(list(0.76,0.52,0.93,NULL),letters[1:4]),envir = globalenv())
```